# Uploading file to icloud-documents even if the memory is full it doesn't give any error

Tags: cloudkit, icloud-drive, icloud-documents

I use iCloud documents  to sync file between device. it works correctly but the main issue is, when iCloud exceed to 5 GB which is maximum allowed for free account, so in this case when I upload the file it continue to write in FileManager but I can not see in another device this because the memory of iCloud is full. But it doesnt give any error feedback using **write(to:)** method. so my question is how to know if iCloud storage is full in order to show error to the user?

so

Comment: I'm seeing the same. It seems to save the file to a sort of "local iCloud Drive staging area"...if you free up space in iCloud, then the saved file will sync. But I'd like to get some notification in my app that there wasn't space...

Comment: I tried with new beta version but still same issue.